# Type Mismatch with InStrRev

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks for reading my question, I keep getting a type mismatch with my function. I read the MS site on InStrRev and it states that it rets an integer. My function is set to return an integer so I'm not sure what I did wrong?

```
Function gSearch(str As String, find As String, Optional dir As String) As Integer
Select Case dir
    Case "L", "l", "left", "Left"
        gSearch = InStrRev(str, find)
    Case "R", "r", "right", "Right"
        gSearch = InStrRev(Len(str), str, find)
    Case Else
        gSearch = InStrRev(str, find)
End Select
```

End Function

Comment: The exact error is "Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch

Answer (score 3):

You are getting your error in the second case of:

```
 Case "R", "r", "right", "Right"
    gSearch = InStrRev(Len(str), str, find)
```

Your first parameter of the **InStrRev** is *Len(str)*.
Len(str) result is a number; The **InStrRev** first parameter needs to be a String.

Comment: @RickFlyFish it happens to all of us, mark as answer